# Asymptotic complexity of sum of poly-logarithmic functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, asymptotics

I'm trying to figure out what's the asymptotic complexity for the following sums:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n lg^s k$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^rlg^s k$$

s and r are positive constants.

I think i should be using integrals for these, but given this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_logarithmic_functions, I just can't find a way to solve these.

Any help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integrals which needed to be guessed looked overly complicated for this problem, i asked a friend at work and we believe that we came up with an answer that does not involve integrals:

$\sum_{k=1}^nlg^sk = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}lg^sk+\sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^nlg^sk\ge$

$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}0+\sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^nlg^s(n/2)=$

$0+n*lg^s(n/2)=\Omega(n*lg^s(n))$

I know the last part is true, but i don't really know how to prove it...

A similar trick can be applied for the upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. You may compare your sums with related integrals.
$$
\int_1^n (\ln x)^sdx-(\ln (n+1))^s\leq\sum_{k=1}^n (\ln k)^s \leq\int_1^n (\ln x)^sdx,\quad n\geq1.
$$ Then observe that, as $n \to \infty$,

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_1^n (\ln x)^s\:dx&=n\:(\ln n)^s-s\int_1^n (\ln x)^{s-1}\:dx\sim n\:(\ln n)^s.
> \end{align}
> $$

Similarly, as $n \to \infty$,

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_1^n x^r(\ln x)^s\:dx&=n^r\:(\ln n)^s-s\int_1^n x^{r-1}(\ln x)^{s-1}\:dx
> \sim n^r\:(\ln n)^s.
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: thanks but i think i found a more elegant solution for this. I would appreciate help with that last bit that i mentioned though...